# MKNumberBadgeView Showing Wrong Text Color in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-graphics, uicolor, nsattributedstring

I'm having an issue with MKNumberBadgeView that only shows up in iOS7. In `initState`, I have `self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` but when the numberBadge is displayed, the text color is black.

The only change that I've made to the MKNumberBadgeView class is changing `CGSize numberSize = [numberString sizeWithFont:self.font];` to `CGSize numberSize = [numberString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font}];` because sizeWithFont was depreciated in iOS7.

Does anyone know why it isn't using the color that I'm telling it to use?

Thanks

EDIT:
I've done some investigating, and it seems like `sizeWithAttributes` is the problem here. I used another third party class to create a badge, and the same problem came up when I added in `sizeWithAttributes`. I've tried `CGSize numberSize = [numberString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];` and that still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

For calculating the size of the number string, the colour is irrelevant. You probably have forgotten to change another piece of code where the text actually gets drawn at a point:

```
//[numberString drawAtPoint:textPt withFont:self.font]; //this is deprecated
[numberString drawAtPoint:textPt 
           withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.font,
                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.textColor}];
```

You have to set the font colour there.

Comment: I had the same issue with https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge. Ever since iOS7's release, Xcode warned about deprecated use of "sizeWithFont". I kept putting off the move to "withAttributes", as the App compiled fine. But with iOS8 around the corner, I decided to remove all of my warnings. And, as soon as I did, the CustomBadge, I'm using, gave me a black text colour. Adding the NSForegroundColorAttributeName, fixed things for me. So, not sure why this question / (answer) has not been voted as correct. This worked for me.